# Mesh downloaded from Google's 3D Warehouse is rendered weirdly

Tags: 3d, vertex, ogre

I downloaded this model from 3D Warehouse: http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/details?mid=a4295f6b93a3e11488961f28097fe890&prevstart=0

Now when it's imported through Open Asset Import library with using OgreAssImp wrapper, I'm encountering following problem with the mesh: [Mesh with weird vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXq4s.png)

So that model is converted from Collada mesh to Ogre mesh and then rendered on the screen.
That has probably something to do with vertexes which are not handled correctly. I'm not really clear about how these 3d things should be handled correctly and that's why I used that OgreAssImp wrapper mentioned above.

I'm relying on someones well trained eye to give me some hints which could be causing that problem. Many of the other 3DWH models are shown correctly, about 90% of them. Also when I tested that model in blender it showed up nice.

So it would be nice if someone could give me some clues :)
Thanks in advance

-Joni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue where Tentdome's indices couldn't fit into 16-bit index buffer. Tebtdine's meshes contain so much indices, that there's need for 32-bit index buffer.
If for some reason that doesn't work, OpenAssetImport has properties you can use for splitting your mesh into smaller meshes, lesser indices, under 16-bit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the normals are reversed for all the polygons.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. I quickly tested setting all materials two sided but that didn't help the case.

Comment: I reversed all the polygons but I'm still having the same problem :E